Setting field alias in GeoPackage file outside of QGIS
In QGIS it's easy to set field aliases for GPKG, or any file that supports it.
Can this be done externally to QGIS (specifically for GPKG) so that when opened in QGIS, it will show said alias alongside the field name in the file table properties?

Yes. I did a quick test, and if you add the alias to a GeoPackage and then open the GeoPackage in another QGIS project, the alias is retained.
So I had a look at the GeoPackage, and the alias is stored in a table called gpkg_data_columns in the Geopackage file, in the column called name:

So if you use any software to create that table and/or update the name column, QGIS will read the alias there. FIY: I haven't tested it, but based on the source code, it looks like the SetAlternativeName function in GDAL will end up saving in gpkg_data_columns.name for GeoPackage files.
Apparently this metadata table is an extension to the basic GPKG standard, so it is not a QGIS-specific thing: https://www.geopackage.org/guidance/extensions/schema.html

I tried with sqlite3 to access this gpkg_data_column table, but it says sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: gpkg_data_column. Can you still see it in your DBMS ?

@Taras: the table is only created by QGIS once you add an alias.

@Taras: sorry, typo: the table is called gpkg_data_columns
